# Sorting based on character code values on a dataframe column

Tags: python, dataframe, sorting

Below is the first column(0th) from a DF
Need to sort it based on character code values(Digits are the lowest value characters and followed by uppercase letter, followed by lowercase letters)

```
tried with sort_values() and sorted() but no luck


USOM042000D89UPC0001
USOM021007D19UPC0001
USOM04200AA0FUPC0001
063899500430
USOM00330AD6DUPC0001
USOM0030828C0UPC0001
USOM043002C05UPC0002
USOM042004F74UPC0001
068542802075
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by mapping the built-in [`ord`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=ord#ord) function over each character:

```py
>>> vals = """USOM042000D89UPC0001
... USOM021007D19UPC0001
... USOM04200AA0FUPC0001
... 063899500430
... USOM00330AD6DUPC0001
... USOM0030828C0UPC0001
... USOM043002C05UPC0002
... USOM042004F74UPC0001
... 068542802075""".splitlines()
>>> vals
['USOM042000D89UPC0001', 'USOM021007D19UPC0001', 'USOM04200AA0FUPC0001', '063899500430', 'USOM00330AD6DUPC0001', 'USOM0030828C0UPC0001', 'USOM043002C05UPC0002', 'USOM042004F74UPC0001', '068542802075']
>>> sorted(vals, key=lambda x: tuple(ord(c) for c in x))
['063899500430', '068542802075', 'USOM0030828C0UPC0001', 'USOM00330AD6DUPC0001', 'USOM021007D19UPC0001', 'USOM042000D89UPC0001', 'USOM042004F74UPC0001', 'USOM04200AA0FUPC0001', 'USOM043002C05UPC0002']
```

Comment: I need to do this simultaneously to multiple columns in a DF. lets say I have total seven columns in a DF named 1 to 7 and I need to sort the DF based on column values 6, 2 and 3. column values when I say it should sort based on character code values